# Add mirror modifier to linked object

Tags: modifiers, add-on

I have linked an object and I want to add a mirror modifier, but there are no options in the properties tab to add modifier. How can I add mirror modifier to a linked object. Is there any addon or how? Any suggestion or Help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot** add modifiers to linked objects in Blender.

Although there is a solution to your problem.

**First Step**

Select the object and press CTRL+G to add it to a Group.

You can give the group a name by pressing the F6 key and enter a new name.

Save the file and then open a new file to go on with step 2.

[image: Add the object to be mirrored to a group]

**Second Step**

Link the group into the new file.

Linking the group is similar to linking an object, but you go inside the Group folder and select the group name instead.

**Third Step**

Select the group instance that was added from previous step and press the space key. Then type Make Proxy and select the name of the object that you want to be mirrored.

[image: Making a proxy of the group instance]

**Fourth Step**

Now select the object whose name ends in _proxy and add a mirror modifier.

**Summary**

Your mesh is still linked and any updates you make in the original file will get updated in the current file where you linked.

Comment: did not get what is 1st step

Comment: My bad. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @satishgoda to make screen capture in blender press Ctrl+F3 and save the image, you can also choose to save the whole interface or the active window. Images from cellphones are very hard to read. See: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Greylica/Doc:2.6/Manual/Vitals/Screenshots

Comment: @cegaton Yes, I understand. I am having some internet problems on my laptop at the moment.

Comment: @satishgoda The problem im getting is before group i have 112 object and i have a group. And when link in a new file and click on the make proxy its drop all 112 object list and selected to one object only its get modifier applied to it not whole model. A sample file i have attach i have 3 object (square, cube and sphere) when done proxy drop down on 3 object to cube its selected its apply modifier for that. I want to apply to my link object which is entire group and not a particular object. Thanks

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3373" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3373/)

Comment: Well in your case, a Python script must be used to automate the making proxy step and creating the mirror modifier.

Comment: If it is possible, you can join the meshes of all the  individual objects, then you can make one proxy and create the mirror modifier (as illustrated in my example)

Comment: is there any addon (python script) available?

Comment: As far as I know, I do not know of any script that does this.